# Have a image twice the height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am currently developing a website, and I have run across an issue in my HTML/CSS. I am open to solutions in HTML, CSS or Jquery.
My issue is as follows:

I want an image to have width: 99%; height: 199%;.
This won't work though. When I run this in chrome, the image goes width: 99%, but height only shows about 90%. Why is this? Can I fix it?

Comment: Is it a repeatable image? If so, just put it in a correctly sized div with `repeat-y`. If not, why the hell do you need to stretch an image vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ancestor elements should have a height defined.

Add a rule for html and body:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
img{
    width:99%; 
    height:199%
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" />
```

Comment: Verify if your body tag have overflow: hidden. It's a possible error

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you html and body class in your css is not set at 100%
then you can try something like this

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="width:99%; height:199%" />
```

I think that should work.